# vim8 - why does my 0read not read?

Tags: vimscript, autocmd, functions, vim8, autoload

I have the following function in an autoload file:

```
function! closet#FindSkeletonForFile()
    if exists('b:closet_skeleton')
        return 0
    endif

    let b:closet_skeleton = s:closet.find_skeleton_for_file(expand('%:p'), &filetype)

    if b:closet_skeleton !=# ''
        let cpopts = &cpoptions
        set cpoptions-=a
        echom "Here goes the read:"
        execute '0read '.fnameescape(b:closet_skeleton)
        let &cpoptions = cpopts
        return 1
    endif

    return 0
endfunction
```

This is triggered by a BufNewFile autocommand, and it appears to be working. The autocmd is in my `plugin/closet.vim` file, and looks like this:

```
augroup closet
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufNewFile * call  closet#FindSkeletonForFile()
augroup END
```

When I invoke `vi foo.vim` (a file that does not exist) I get an empty buffer, some of my earlier code identifies valid skeletons, I get a confirm dialog, the filename is returned, and the `s:closet.find_skeleton_for_file(...)` function returns the correct value.

My `echom` outputs to the message log, and when I run `:mess` in the new vim window, I see this:

```
Messages maintainer: Bram Moolenaar <Bram@vim.org>
Here goes the read:
"~/Code/aghast/vim-closet/Closet/plugin.vim" 28L, 448C
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

This tells me that the dummy plugin is being read **somewhere**, since those line/character numbers are what I see when I edit the dummy file.

But the `foo.vim` buffer doesn't get changed! Since I can see the code being run correctly (many, many :echom statements) I'm pretty sure it's just down to getting that `0read` statement to ... well, read!

Can someone clue me in on the obvious thing I've missed?

Comment: After you get an empty buffer for new file `foo.vim`... if you run `:execute '0read '.fnameescape(b:closet_skeleton)` by hand, does it properly populate the file with the contents of the intended skeleton file?

Comment: Yes, it does. And I get the filepath in the message log with the same numbers, to boot.

Comment: And it's somewhat comforting that the `b:closet_skeleton` buffer variable has been set, so at least my script is getting that right.

Comment: Is it possible the `0read` is actually reading but another hook is later erasing the buffer? Maybe try to test that without other plug-ins loaded to see if that works?

Comment: Might be. I ran `vim -u NONE`, then did `:set rtp+=~/.../vim-closet`, then `:e foo.vim` and the template appeared. Now to slowly remove directories...

Comment: @filbranden++ ! It turns out I had a hook installed that was doing find-file-if-not-exist on VimEnter, and it wasn't checking for contents. Modified that to check where the `line('$')` pointed to, and quit if the buffer had contents, and now all is well! Thanks.

Comment: I wrote an answer based on what we did to solve this issue, based on the comments. This way we can go ahead and resolve this question, so it doesn't keep showing as unanswered... Feel free to edit the answer if you'd like to add or change details. Really glad you figured out this one fairly quickly! Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `0read` on BufNewFile actually works as expected, in fact the documentation for BufNewFile explicitly mentions using that event for loading a template or skeleton file.

If we also rule out the other things that might have gone wrong there, then the most likely explanation is that `0read` *is* working, but the contents of the buffer are later erased by another plug-in or hook.

As we ruled out anything else from that code path specifically (the `b:closet_skeleton` was being set, and running the `0read` from it after opening Vim was loading the file correctly), then the next course of action is to [debug your vimrc file](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/18609).

Following those steps, you were able to find you had a hook on VimEnter doing "find-file-if-not-exist" that was creating interference with your skeleton file hook. Updating that hook to consider previous contents of a file was enough to break that interference.

Comment: I too hate having resolved issues in the Unanswered section. +1!